# How to deal with a user whose edits I feel are problematic?

Tags: discussion

My question is in reference to the one I asked [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/154873/why-is-external-access-to-a-server-via-ssh-considered-insecure).

It seems like the question was originally treated like I had some misconception about the subject I was asking about but when pressed for what that was I received no response. Unfortunately I believe I need to single a user out - schroeder - as the cause of my confusion, as all responses I received acted like he had made an explanation but if he did I am not aware of it. To date he hasn't spoken to arguments I brought up first in comments, then in the main post by editing, and has kept deleting or removing those edits.

I was told to post here but am not sure what I really need to ask about. I am trying to keep the conversation above board and light in accusations, but I find that hard to do, and am very confused as to how my question and I were treated.

Unfortunately many of the comments I would like to discuss have been pruned by the user I feel is problematic. Should I list my grievances, move on, or simply leave the site?

**EDIT:** Essentially what happened is I disagreed with a user who was editing my post. I asked for an explanation as to why the edits were taking place but was given none despite their claims to the contrary. I hold that none of the responses ever spoke to any of the points I brought up despite claims to contrary. All discussion which took place about this topic in the comments has been deleted.

If my questions were indeed answered, why was the discussion not left intact? It seems relevant to the topic and undoubtedly others will have the same question.

Comment: You were editing comments and arguments into the question text where they don't belong. As I understand it, the deletions were meant to remove clutter to keep the question concise and straightforward. If you're unsatisfied with a particular answer you can always ask for clarification in a comment.

Comment: @Arminius: I tried to speak to the user making the edits but they were not interested in opening a dialogue at all and ignored my repeated questions in the comments. I switched to editing the main post as a last resort.

Answer (score 6):

Your original question was unanswerable. What I, and those responding, was trying to do was to discover what the core question was so that we could actually respond to you.

To ask, "why is X insecure?" requires that there be some understanding that X is insecure. So, first, there needs to be some common ground on that point. To ask "someone said X is insecure, why is X insecure?" is a non-starter. There can be no common ground with a non-exisitent 3rd party. As I mentioned in my comments, we cannot tell you why someone else thinks something.

By asking for context and details, the hope is that we can discover why, perhaps, *we* might conclude X is insecure, given certain conditions. That's why I, and others, asked for context and details.

I made all these points in my comments.

Your misconception is not about SSH, but about how this site works. We are a Q&A site with the hopes that other people might discover someone else who has asked the same question they currently have. That means the questions need to have some level of universality and generality to have a hope to be a question someone else might ask with applicable answers. Hence, editing to provide guidance to those answering (to get you some kind of answer) and to provide a level of universality.

Further to that end, the body of the question needs to stand on its own. I remove your editorials because they are not a part of the question, but comments.

If you want "supporting evidence" for something, then you need to phrase your question to ask for that. Your question currently is, "what did I miss?"

Also, we are not s discussion site. Questions are not to be prompts for back-and-forth opinions.

After reading all your comments and your edits, it appears that over time, you have revealed your core question: "How can I prove to someone else that SSH is secure?" If this is so, then you have not asked this question at all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68433/discussion-on-answer-by-rory-alsop-how-to-deal-with-a-user-whose-edits-i-feel-ar).

Answer (score 3):

After seeing your continued attempts to edit in a way unsuitable (despite having these edits removed by various moderators) I have locked the post against further alteration.

The problem here is not with @schroeder's activities, which have been to try to improve the question to an acceptable level. It is with your insistence on changing things against our site guidance.

Please take the hint - edits weren't made because people couldn't answer the question. They were made because the question was not suitably worded.

As I mentioned in comments, this would be plain if you read and understood our site tour and our help pages. If you then decide this isn't the site for you, as you mentioned, then that's fine, but when here you do need to abide by the rules the site works by.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68433/discussion-on-answer-by-rory-alsop-how-to-deal-with-a-user-whose-edits-i-feel-ar).